# Can you tame a rabbit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have watched a few David videos and have noticed he has this pet rabbit. It follows him around and hops when he hops. I was wondering if it's possible to tame a rabbit.

Comment: Who is David..?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Minecraft Wiki:

As of 14w34a (1.8): "Rabbits can no longer be tamed and do not flee from players."

This may have changed in 1.9, but there is no data about it on the Wiki yet.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rabbit

Comment: That link says they can be bread with carrots, golden carrots, and dandelions. If holding one of those, they will follow until you let them reproduce or you switch to a different item.

Comment: That's breeding, not taming. That is true if you are attempting to breed rabbits.